# Anonymize IP logging in nginx error.log

Tags: nginx, logging, ip, error-log, anonymize

For access.log it is possible:
[Anonymize IP logging in nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477239/anonymize-ip-logging-in-nginx)

But, is there also any possibility to anonymize IP logging in the error.log?

Comment: Have you found an answer?

Comment: Sorry @Tim for the late response. Unfortunately, I didn't find the answer there. But it could be that there is now something available - I don't know because it became not so relevant for me anymore. Maybe someone else is posting one day a good answer here! :-)