# How to change log message format for LUA in NGINX?

Tags: nginx, lua

Now I use

```
ngx.log(ngx.ALERT , "This is my message");
```

method to log messages in LUA. It gives a very descriptive message as shown in following. So how can I change the log format in NGINX to just output my alert message?

```
2017/03/19 12:32:10 [alert] 21994#0: *9 [lua] content_by_lua(proj1.conf:159):3: **This is my message**, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /service/user_info?access_token=323d106b-b170-4e91-9296-ef1a38b5af19 HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:4000"
```

**EDIT**

I use this directive in nginx http block,

```
error_log stderr info;
```

Comment: https://devdocs.io/nginx/http/ngx_http_log_module#log_format

Comment: @hjpotter92: Thanks, But how can I use log_format for error_log directive? As I see in the documentation it is for access_log directive.

Comment: it not possible to change error log format. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4246756/is-it-possible-to-specify-custom-error-log-format-in-nginx While core nginx build a prefix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711573/nginx-error-log-format-documentation, nginx_lua_module also adds its own part - [lua] content_by_lua(proj1.conf:159):3:. IMO without this prefix logs are useless

Answer (score 0):

you could do `io.stderr:write("This is my message")`

Answer (score 0):

the constant prefix and suffix in error_log always boring me.

as a final workaround, I open file and write to it.

// in nginx `http` context

```
lua_shared_dict file_dict 1m;
```

// in lua

```lua
            local file = ngx.shared.file_dict:get("log_file")
            if not file then
                file = io.open("/tmp/custom.log", "a")
                ngx.shared.file_dict:set("log_file", file)
                ngx.log(ngx.WARN, "--- open file")
            end

            file:write(string.format("str %s num %d\\n", "abc", 456))
            file:flush()
```